# Is it better to cache a large number of records on client side, or do multiple smaller requests to Salesforce?

Tags: soql, rest-api, ruby

In an application I'm developing in Ruby, I want to create a pagination system so that on the first page, the first 10 results show up, then the second 10 on the 2nd page, and so on. I know I can query a specific number of records doing something like

`Select Id from Account limit 10 offset 10`

and it would return records 11-20. However, I don't know if this is the best practice. My question is two-fold:

1. Is it better to query a large number of records on the client side, then go through them from memory, or query a small set each time I change the page? And,
2. Will the total request time be much different for both queries in *1.*? I've just started to work with Salesforce and `SOQL` so I don't know how optimized Salesforce is for large data queries.

Comment: Have you considered using pagination with a StandardSetController ? There are ViewState and HeapSize limits which means it has to be a balancing act.

Comment: I'm not using APEX, but Ruby, so I don't think I can use `StandardSetController`.

Comment: My bad, didn't spot that. From an API standpoint it would make sense to have a cache and sync when needed, I would imagine API calls are expensive and there could be limits if you're hosting in the cloud. Salesforce is highly optimised for large data queries particularly when using indexed fields (ids or external ids) in the where clause.

Comment: OFFSET is limited to 2,000 records, so, barring "memory constraints", I'd recommend using client-side as much as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from your [API Call Limit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm), I would definitely process the records client-side, and just use SFDC as a platform / UI. I'm not the authority, but I would assume this is *best practice / most convenient*

If your trying to handle *really large* sets of data *on the server side*. I'd consider the `Bulk API` http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/

Though if your interfacing to the data and want to paginate, just grab a results set and *process it* client side with your APP or pass it to the page and use Javascript there to display your results...you can move a lot of stuff with JSON relatively quickly and with low-overhead.